# control stepper motors with an arduino via ROS

Tags: control, ros, arduino, rosserial-arduino

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I have a robotic Arm composed of stepper motors Nema 23 with encoders. I'm using an arduino Mega to control it.
I want to build my arm with ROS. This arm will be used to grasp objects through inverse kinematics, after getting the object coordinates in the space.

I'm new to ROS and I need any help or steps on how to do it.
Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/276020/control-stepper-motors-with-an-arduino-via-ros/) by [nadaanas1988](https://answers.ros.org/users/32646/nadaanas1988/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2017-11-15

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there! I've done this before, it depends on which shield you are using to control it, I assume you are using a shield for Arduino right?
There is [one node already for a raspberry shield](https://github.com/matpalm/ros-motorhat-node)  but I bet that is not the one you are using.

If you are using the ST L6470 stepper controller then check out [this link](https://github.com/Buzzzsaw/ROS-L6470). That is the node you should be using. If you are controlling the stepper directly from the Arduino from the digital pins, don't do that, since you'll probably kill your Arduino due to current use.

If you provide more info about the shield you are using I can help further.

---

Originally posted by [bpinaya](https://answers.ros.org/users/28465/bpinaya/) with karma: 700 on 2017-11-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0